# Detect if Object3D is receiving shadows (r86)

Tags: javascript, three.js, collision-detection, shadow

I'd like to do be able to detect if an object is in shadow or not. What would be the best, most performant way to do this?

Eg., There's a tree in the scene and a directional light. Move a character under the tree and they are now standing in the tree'a shadow which it casts. How can you detect at what point they have entered / left the tree's cast shadow?

Comment: Your question is not so clear to understand what you exactly want. You need to re-work it. For clarification, could you also add an image with the desired result?

Comment: @prisoner849 updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the ultimate solution, this is just an option you can use as the start point.

And this is just a translation of my answer from another segment of stackoverflow.com, dedicated to Three.js.

The idea: you set a ray from the point along the direction to a light source, and, if it intersects any object, then the point is in the shadow, otherwise, it's not.

Given: point on a plane `pointOnPlane`, a normalized vector of the position of a directional light source (which will be our direction) `direction` and an array of objects in the scene `sceneObjects` (which we want to find intersection with). To determine, if the point is shaded or not, we'll need a short function:

```
var raycasterPoint = new THREE.Raycaster();
var direction = new THREE.Vector3();// for re-use

function isShaded(pointOnPlane){
  direction.copy(light.position).normalize();
  raycasterPoint.set(pointOnPlane, direction); // ray's origin and direction
  var retVal = false;
  var pointIntersects = raycasterPoint.intersectObjects( sceneObjects );
  if (pointIntersects.length > 0) retVal = true;
  return retVal;
}
```

[image: Is point shaded]

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/v5hsyexw/) example.

Comment: Ok yes! I presume you could also cast a ray from the object in question to the light source and see if it hit a shadow casting object or not. My only concern is perhaps that this solution can't cover shadows caused by anything but directional lights. But maybe the solution needs to change depending on the light type.

Comment: You can subtract the position of an object from the position of a light source (if it's not a directional light), then normalize it, thus you'll get the direction.